# Does apple force you to go through ApplePay for in-app purchases and subscriptions?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, subscription, applepay

i am running a cordova app. And was planning to add some premium features to it for users paying monthly subscription.
I am looking into stripe payments for that and they allow you to bill your users monthly.

But my questions is 
- does apple allow to go through stripe for subscriptions or other in-app payments or does apple force you to go through ApplePay.
- if apple forces you to only deal with ApplePay and not other payment processors, can anyone shed some light on how it works in cordova app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically, users can subscribe to services outside of the App and then make use of those services through the App with the need to go through ApplePay (or attract Apple tax), see Netflix.  The problem is, you can not make any mention of the services in anyway or direct users to an external site which makes mention of the paid services from within the App - Apple will see that as a "in app purchase" - and yes, it's all murky and open to interpretation

Answer (score 0):

Yes Apple forces you to pay them somewhere between 15 and 30% for any payments done from within the app. Unfortunately you're gonna have to have a separate payment gateway setup online (a static page on a webpage which you can host practically anywhere for free and throw in some stripe form to process your payments) big apps like Netflix have the same issue and they simply process their payments their website.

Comment: Thanks @Karim. 
You mean apple doesnt mind if on click of subscribe button, app redirects user to webpage that handles their card info etc. and let them subscribe?

Comment: Unfortunately Apple explicitly says in their terms that apps with a buy or subscribe button redirecting to a payment gateway outside the app store will get rejected. So it has to be put more implicitly or from within your webpage. So putting a link also won't work. But you can write it in text I assume i.e. let's say you have a price list withing your app inside that list write down in text log in <- this can be a link to the website for example, and go to payments page to proceed. This way you somewhat don't break the terms

Comment: Can users manage their credit cards i.e. add new card or update existing expired card details within the app or does that need to be done outside the app?

Comment: @Andy Grey area, but I would "suggest" that based on the wording, if they user is managing their subscription in anyway, that would be fall under Apples in-app purchasing, when in doubt, just do it all externally